# mysql error, stored procedure creation

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and I cant see why I have an error when I create my stored procedure.

```
   DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE lastscan(IN task_id_var INT)
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM debugger WHERE task_id=task_id_var INTO @total|
  SET @total=@total+1|
  INSERT INTO debugger SET scan_num=@total, task_id=task_id_var|
END|
DELIMITER;
```

I get :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

I also dont get, why do I need to use that delimiter syntax.. ?  DELIMITER | and then again  DELIMITER;...what its function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE lastscan(IN task_id_var INT, IN file_name_var VARCHAR(110))
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM debugger WHERE task_id=task_id_var INTO @total;
  SET @total=@total+1;
  INSERT INTO debugger SET scan_num=@total, task_id=task_id_var, file_name=file_name_var;
END|
DELIMITER;
```

This works for me. no need to put | delimiter in sored procedure. I think it is meant to be for the stored procedure and not for what is inside the body

Answer (score -1):

You can't simply assign variables like that, you need the `SET` keyword first.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html

So you code should be something like this (tested with phpMyAdmin):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE lastscan(IN task_id_var INT)
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM debugger WHERE task_id=task_id_var INTO @total;
  SET @total=@total+1;
  INSERT INTO debugger SET scan_num=@total, task_id=task_id_var;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

The DELIMITER keyword is used to stop additional semicolons in your procedure to be the end of the current statement, so by redefining the delimiter to // MySql will process the whole CREATE PROCEDURE-block as one single statement and not stop at the first semicolon but instead wait for the first occurrence of //.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: very interesting the example in the book that I have actually uses ; inside the stored procedure..I will check your code now

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? I ran this query on a MySql 5.5 and it worked fine.

Comment: Actuallly you are right, you can use ; as delimiter inside your procedure, works just as well when I tested it.

Comment: mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 318113 $
doesnt work for me. The body of the stored procedure works..but hte stored procedure itself isnt created

Comment: Hm, just as a small notion, add a space between DELIMITER and ; on the last line (which is technically line 3 since the whole CREATE PROCEDURE is one single statement).

Comment: it didnt help, i made a new line between each statement..which equals space. It still says that there is an error near BEGIN

Comment: How are you exeuting this query? Using the mysql commandline interface or do you have another tool for it? I tried running the same query using PhpMyAdmin and that failed with the same error that you are getting.

Comment: I've updated the code sample with one that I've tested to work with phpMyAdmin and HeidiSQL (which I regularly use).